# Pandas find year ago date from non-uniform list of dates

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, date, datetime

I could use some more help with a project. I am trying to analyze 4.5 million rows of data. I have read the data into a dataframe, have organized the data and now have 3 columns: 1) date as datetime 2) unique identifier 3) price

I need to calculate the year over year change in prices per item but the dates are not uniform and not consistent per item. For example:

```
date      item  price
12/31/15   A     110
12/31/15   B     120
12/31/14   A     100
6/24/13    B     100
```

What I would like is to find as a result is:

```
date      item  price  previousdate   % change
12/31/15   A     110   12/31/14       10%
12/31/15   B     120   6/24/13        20%
12/31/14   A     100
6/24/13    B     100
```

**EDIT** - Better example of data

```
 date   item    price
6/1/2016    A   276.3457646
6/1/2016    B   5.044165645
4/27/2016   B   4.91300186
4/27/2016   A   276.4329163
4/20/2016   A   276.9991265
4/20/2016   B   4.801263717
4/13/2016   A   276.1950213
4/13/2016   B   5.582923328
4/6/2016    B   5.017863509
4/6/2016    A   276.218649
3/30/2016   B   4.64274783
3/30/2016   A   276.554653
3/23/2016   B   5.576438253
3/23/2016   A   276.3135836
3/16/2016   B   5.394435443
3/16/2016   A   276.4222986
3/9/2016    A   276.8929462
3/9/2016    B   4.999951262
3/2/2016    B   4.731349423
3/2/2016    A   276.3972068
1/27/2016   A   276.8458971
1/27/2016   B   4.993033132
1/20/2016   B   5.250379701
1/20/2016   A   276.2899864
1/13/2016   B   5.146639666
1/13/2016   A   276.7041978
1/6/2016    B   5.328296958
1/6/2016    A   276.9465891
12/30/2015  B   5.312301356
12/30/2015  A   256.259668
12/23/2015  B   5.279105491
12/23/2015  A   255.8411198
12/16/2015  B   5.150798234
12/16/2015  A   255.8360529
12/9/2015   A   255.4915183
12/9/2015   B   4.722876886
12/2/2015   A   256.267146
12/2/2015   B   5.083626167
10/28/2015  B   4.876177757
10/28/2015  A   255.6464653
10/21/2015  B   4.551439655
10/21/2015  A   256.1735769
10/14/2015  A   255.9752668
10/14/2015  B   4.693967392
10/7/2015   B   4.911797443
10/7/2015   A   256.2556707
9/30/2015   B   4.262994526
9/30/2015   A   255.8068691
7/1/2015    A   255.7312385
4/22/2015   A   234.6210132
4/15/2015   A   235.3902076
4/15/2015   B   4.154926102
4/1/2015    A   234.4713827
2/25/2015   A   235.1391496
2/18/2015   A   235.1223471
```

What I have done (with some help from other users) hasn't worked but is below. Thanks for any help you guys can provide or pointing me in the right direction!

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('...python test file5.csv',parse_dates =['As of Date'])

df = df[['item','price','As of Date']]

def get_prev_year_price(x, df):
    try:
        return df.loc[x['prev_year_date'], 'price']
        #return np.abs(df.time - x)
    except Exception as e:
        return x['price']

#Function to determine the closest date from given date and list of all dates
def nearest(items, pivot):
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))

df['As of Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['As of Date'],format='%m/%d/%Y')
df = df.rename(columns = {df.columns[2]:'date'})

# list of dates
dtlst = [item for item in df['date']]

data = []
data2 = []
for item in df['item'].unique():
    item_df = df[df['item'] == item] #select based on items
    select_dates = item_df['date'].unique()
    item_df.set_index('date', inplace=True) #set date as key index

    item_df = item_df.resample('D').mean().reset_index() #fill in missing date
    item_df['price'] = item_df['price'].interpolate('nearest') #fill in price with nearest price available
    # use max(item_df['date'] where item_df['date'] < item_df['date'] - pd.DateOffset(years=1, days=1))
        #possible_date = item_df['date'] - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
        #item_df['prev_year_date'] = max(df[df['date'] <= possible_date])

    item_df['prev_year_date'] = item_df['date'] - pd.DateOffset(years=1) #calculate 1 year ago date
    date_df = item_df[item_df.date.isin(select_dates)] #select dates with useful data
    item_df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

    date_df['prev_year_price'] = date_df.apply(lambda x: get_prev_year_price(x, item_df),axis=1)
    #date_df['prev_year_price'] = date_df.apply(lambda x: nearest(dtlst, x),axis=1)

    date_df['change'] = date_df['price'] / date_df['prev_year_price']-1
    date_df['item'] = item
    data.append(date_df)
    data2.append(item_df)
summary = pd.concat(data).sort_values('date', ascending=False)
#print (summary)

#saving the output of the CSV file to see how data looks after being handled 
filename = '...python_test_file_save4.csv'
summary.to_csv(filename, index=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Is there at most one price per year per item?

Comment: Unfortunately not, there would be at most about 50 per item per year

Comment: you need to precisely define what year over year means

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. What I mean by year over year is that given a more recent date like item B in the above, on 12/31/15 if I look back 1 year, the price at 12/31/14 would be the price that was set on 6/24/13. Lets say there is also item C that has prices as of 12/31/15, 1/31/15, 11/14/14, 11/19/13, and 11/14/13.  The year over year price needed when calculating for the 12/31/15 date is the price that was set on 11/14/14, the price needed for the 1/31/15 is the price set on 11/19/13 and the price needed for 11/14/14 was the price set on 11/14/13

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It would be a good idea to recreate the sample dataframe that you provided and expected result. Generally, you want to make an example that captures the different possibilities.

Comment: @TedPetrou I added in a better example of the data, taken from the dataframe for an example with just 2 items. In reality there are over 4500 unique items so trying to post an easier to deal with portion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good situation for `merge_asof`, which merges two dataframes by finding the last row of the right dataframe that is less than the key to the left dataframe. We need to add a year to the right dataframe first, since the requirement is 1 year or more difference between dates.

Here is some sample data that you brought up in your comment.

```
date      item  price
12/31/15   A     110
12/31/15   B     120
12/31/14   A     100
6/24/13    B     100
12/31/15   C     100
1/31/15    C      80
11/14/14   C     130
11/19/13   C     110
11/14/13   C     200
```

The dates need to be sorted for `merge_asof` to work. `merge_asof` also drops the joining column so we need to put a copy of that back in our right dataframe.

**Setup dataframes**

```
df = df.sort_values('date')
df_copy = df.copy()
df_copy['previousdate'] = df_copy['date']
df_copy['date'] += pd.DateOffset(years=1)
```

**Use `merge_asof`**

```
df_final = pd.merge_asof(df, df_copy, 
                        on='date', 
                        by='item', 
                        suffixes=['current', 'previous'])
df_final['% change'] = (df_final['pricecurrent'] - df_final['priceprevious']) / df_final['priceprevious']
df_final

        date item  pricecurrent  priceprevious previousdate  % change
0 2013-06-24    B           100            NaN          NaT       NaN
1 2013-11-14    C           200            NaN          NaT       NaN
2 2013-11-19    C           110            NaN          NaT       NaN
3 2014-11-14    C           130          200.0   2013-11-14 -0.350000
4 2014-12-31    A           100            NaN          NaT       NaN
5 2015-01-31    C            80          110.0   2013-11-19 -0.272727
6 2015-12-31    A           110          100.0   2014-12-31  0.100000
7 2015-12-31    B           120          100.0   2013-06-24  0.200000
8 2015-12-31    C           100          130.0   2014-11-14 -0.230769
```

Comment: Wow, that was hugely helpful - thanks a ton for your help with this!!

Answer (score 2):

With current usecase assumptions, this works out for this specific usecase

```
In [2459]: def change(grp):
      ...:     grp['% change'] = grp.price.diff()
      ...:     grp['previousdate'] = grp.date.shift(1)
      ...:     return grp
```

Sort on `date` then `groupby` and `apply` the `change` function, then sort the index back.

```
In [2460]: df.sort_values('date').groupby('item').apply(change).sort_index()
Out[2460]:
        date item  price  % change previousdate
0 2015-12-31    A    110      10.0   2014-12-31
1 2015-12-31    B    120      20.0   2013-06-24
2 2014-12-31    A    100       NaN          NaT
3 2013-06-24    B    100       NaN          NaT
```

Comment: yeah that works for this one case but unfortunately I dont think it will work for the actual data as there are thousands of items ... I think I see what you are doing with the dateshift, that might be the key to figuring this out though?